# Factoring parameter-independent code out of templates

Tags: c++, templates, inline

This question refers to Item 44 in the Effective C++ book. Scott Mayers points out that the following template class might incur code bloat since the invert function doesn't necessarily depends on the template parameter n. Unfortunately multiple template instances with different n values, such as SquareMatrix<int, 5> and SquareMatrix<int, 10> would generate multiple instances of the invert function too, thus generating object code greater than what it actually should be.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t n>
class SquareMatrix
{   
public:
   void invert()
   {
      ...
   }
};
```

He suggests that the invert function can be factored out in a base class as follows. Note that the volatile var is there just for test purpose in order to prevent the compiler from optimizing everything out. SquareMatrixBase::invert is not supposed to do anything reasonable. I just wanted to check whether its code is duplicated or not.

```
template<typename T>
class SquareMatrixBase
{
protected:
   void invert(std::size_t size)
   {
      volatile int var = size;
   }
};

template<typename T, std::size_t n>
class SquareMatrix : private SquareMatrixBase<T>
{
private:
   using SquareMatrixBase<T>::invert;

public:
   void invert()
   {
      invert(n);
   }
};
```

At this point Scott Mayers says:

> now many -- maybe all -- of SquareMatrix's member functions can be
>   simple inline calls to non-inline base class versions that are shared
>   with all other matrices holding the same type of data, regardless of
>   their size.

However, I don't understand why the compiler shouldn't inline SquareMatrixBase::invert too, which would incur a code bloat. Why does Scott Mayers talks about "calls to non-inline base class versions"? As far as I now a template class' member function is always implicitly eligible for inlining, unless I force the compiler not to do so through some specific directive.

As a test I compiler the following main function with gcc and O3 optimization level

```
int main()
{
   {
      SquareMatrix<int, 5> sm;
      sm.invert();
   }
   {
      SquareMatrix<int, 10> sm;
      sm.invert();
   }       
   return 0;
}
```

and the resulting object code clearly shows that BaseSquareMatrixBase::invert is inlined, thus causing duplicated object code.

```
0000000000400400 <main>:
class SquareMatrixBase
{
protected:
   void invert(std::size_t size)
   {
      volatile int var = size;
  400400:       c7 44 24 f8 05 00 00    movl   $0x5,-0x8(%rsp)
  400407:       00 
   {
      SquareMatrix<int, 10> sm;
      sm.invert();
   }       
   return 0;
}
  400408:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
class SquareMatrixBase
{
protected:
   void invert(std::size_t size)
   {
      volatile int var = size;
  40040a:       c7 44 24 fc 0a 00 00    movl   $0xa,-0x4(%rsp)
  400411:       00 
   {
      SquareMatrix<int, 10> sm;
      sm.invert();
   }       
   return 0;
}
  400412:       c3                      retq
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this concrete instance, you and the compiler both would want to inline the call to `SquareMatrixBase<int>::invert()`, because it is so small. With a larger `invert()` function, the compiler will make the trade off between inlining or calling — it'd be interesting to see what gcc does with -Os, for example, with a fully implemented `invert()` — but if the base class is not a templated class (or if you are only planning on supporting a finite number of instantiations), you have the option of forcing the issue by providing the implementation in a different compilation unit.

Comment: gcc with -Os inlines SquareMatrixBase<int>::invert() as soon as its body is 8 instructions long, i.e. 64 Bytes on my 64-bit machine. Whereas with -O3 it is inlined when it reaches 16 instructions (128 Bytes).